# Create a passbook with Parse.com

Tags: web-services, parse-platform, token, passbook

I would like to create passbook(.pkpass) by using data in parse.com,
but I need  *"webServiceURL"* and *"authenticationToken"* to connect,but I don't know how to get them?Or how to use REST api to get them?

Comment: Start by reading the documents!  You need to create the REST API yourself.  You supply the webServiceURL that points to the REST API that you create and you also supply the Authentication token yourself.  This token tells your REST API that the device calling it is authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

Both the webServiceUrl and authenticationToken are optional, and only required if you want your pass to support updating (lots of passes don't).

See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/TopLevel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012026-CH2-SW3